# image slideshow using canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create an image slideshow using HTML5 canvas and a little bit of javascript. My problem is the following: the slideshow works with the fading effect that I want for the first passing through the image set, and after that, the images are drawn into the canvas without the effect, and keeps going like that.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="showCanvas" width='600' height='400'>Canvas Not Supported</canvas>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var imagePaths = ["images/j0149014.jpg","images/j0149024.jpg","images/j0149029.jpg"];
        var showCanvas = null;
        var showCanvasCtx = null;
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var currentImage = 0;
        var revealTimer;

        window.onload = function (){
            showCanvas = document.getElementById('showCanvas');
            showCanvasCtx = showCanvas.getContext('2d');
            img.setAttribute('width','600');
            img.setAttribute('height','400');
            setInterval(switchImage,3000);
        }

        function switchImage() {

            img.setAttribute('src',imagePaths[currentImage++]);
            img.onload = function(){
                if(currentImage >= imagePaths.length)
                    currentImage = 0;
                showCanvasCtx.globalAlpha = 0.0;
                revealTimer = setInterval(revealImage,100);
            }
        }

        function revealImage() {
            showCanvasCtx.drawImage(img,0,0,600,400);
            showCanvasCtx.globalAlpha += 0.1;
            if(showCanvasCtx.globalAlpha >= 1.0)
                clearInterval(revealTimer);
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Probably the load event doesn’t fire any more when it starts re-using already loaded images.

Comment: I see that something with this fading animation overwrites in time. I've played with the milliseconds from setInterval calls, and I obtained two passings through the image set with the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons the fading is not working as you expected.

**Don't use ctx.globalAlpha for maths operations**

`ctx.globalAlpha` is not a number, or even a string representing a javascript number. It is a CSS alpha value and should not be referenced to do calculations.

**Why?**

```
if(ctx.globalAlpha >= 1){ //is the problem as it never happens
```

`globalAlpha` is a CSS alpha value. Invalid CSS values are not allowed so `ctx.globalAlpha` will never be greater than 1 as that is an invalid alpha value

The CSS alpha value is not a floating point value, it is the result of a bit of manipulation resulting in incorrect results for mathematical operations.

Your alpha goes up to 0.999999 (thereabouts) then you add 0.1 which results in an invalid alpha. As invalid alpha are not allowed the globalAlpha value is not changed. It stays at 0.99999 and the interval is never canceled.

Thus every time you change the `img` to a new src it is drawn by all the still running interval timers.

Store the alpha in a Javascript variable and use that to set the alpha and test when it is >= 1 rather than use the CSS alpha string in `ctx.globalAlpha`

**Canvas rendering is cumulative**

Drawing white on the canvas with alpha at 0.5 results in a gray pixel, draw again without clearing the canvas and the new pixel is the gray plus white 0.5. The second render results in a white, not gray. 0.5 + 0.5 = 1;

You are drawing the same image on top of its self. First with alpha 0.1 all pixels (10%) then with alpha 0.2 that adds 20% resulting in image pixels at 30%, then 0.3 60% and 0.4 100%. Thus when the alpha is at 0.4 the image is already fully rendered.

You need to keep two copies of the images. The previous image and the new image. Draw the previous image at alpha = 1 and the next at the required alpha (if no previous image clear the canvas)

That should solve the problems you are having.

Comment: Wow! I've used another variable as you suggested and all runs perfectly. Thank you very much!